# Association of models(JOIN) not working in cakephp, shows empty results

Tags: mysql, cakephp, join, model

I am purely new to cakephp and currently working on a project that is built in version `1.3`. Basically I am trying to display the city names of the providers which are inserted in the database. 
I have two models : `gal_store.php` and `gal_location.php`. In the `gal_store` model, the stores names are saved with their corresponding city ids in `city` field in `gal_stores` table. The table `gal_locations` contains all the cities and their names.

So I tried to JOIN the two tables as below :

```
var $hasOne = array(
        'GalLocation' => array(
            'className' => 'GalLocation',
            'foreignKey' => 'id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ),
    );

    function getList($limit = 50,$whether_list = false){
        $recursive = -1;
    $conditions = array("GalStore.city"=> "GalLocation.id");
        //$conditions = "";
    $order = array("GalStore.address");
        if($whether_list == true){
            return $this->find("list",array("DISTINCT GalStore.city","recursive"=>$recursive,"limit"=>$limit,"order"=>$order,"conditions" => $conditions));
        }else{
            return $this->find("all",array("DISTINCT GalStore.city","recursive"=>$recursive,"limit"=>$limit,"order"=>$order,"conditions" => $conditions));    
        }

    }
```

But in the `ctp` file when I do a `var_dump($gal_locations);` it always shows empty ! What is the reason ?

Answer (score 0):

If the gal_locations has one to one relationship with gal_stores, use below code:

```
var $hasOne = array(
    'GalLocation' => array(
        'className' => 'GalLocation',
        'foreignKey' => 'city',//if the city field contains the id of gal_locations table
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
);
```

If the gal_locations has one to many relationship with gal_stores, use below code:

```
var $belongsTo = array(
    'GalLocation' => array(
        'className' => 'GalLocation',
        'foreignKey' => 'city',//if the city field contains the id of gal_locations table
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
);
```